# Git commit is taking a long time

Tags: git

I used the following commands in this order:

`git pull origin master`

`git add .`

`git commit -m 'my third commit'`

And then my Git Shell just shows these characters: **>> _** with the underscore flashing. It's been like this for 10 minutes, whats going on?

Comment: It sounds like you committing a lot of stuff locally? Perhaps large generated binaries? Images?

Comment: On what OS are you? Which shell are you using? Do you have any commit hooks installed?

Comment: Well the shell did say `[master + 56 `0 -0]` so I guess that is a lot of files.

Comment: @Ogen, Commit hooks can also take a long time. It would help us if you gave more details about the nature of the files you are trying to commit.

Comment: Windows, And I dont know how to tell you what shell I'm using, the icon is blue with a play button looking thing, also, in the top left of the window, it says posh~git

Comment: Is pushing slow as well?

Comment: @Maximas Don't you push after a commit? My commit isn't done yet so I don't know.

Comment: @Ogen You're right, you do. I assumed that this was a recurring issue, rather than this being the first occurrence. How many files are within your repo that you've commited? (And have you tried hammering "enter"? That's solved git issues for me before)

Comment: 56 files, I'm going to spam enter and see what happens.

Comment: @Maximas Thanks for that, I spammed and it gave me this random error message saying it couldnt recognise commands. The commands were part of my commit message. And so I looked at my message and I had put a colon (:) in it. I restarted the shell, took out the colon and it commited instantly :)

Comment: Ah, awesome =D If in doubt, spam enter and turn it off and on again :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your other comment, it looks like you're using Powershell.

The >> means that there's an unmatched quotation, parentheses, or other character requiring a match. Git has not yet been executed.

Press Control-C. Look at your commit message. Does it include " or ' or some other special character? If so, take it out or properly escape it.